# Want turtles to disappear once I hit key for displayed letter

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

Here is my code. I want the patties to disappear once I hit the key that is displayed on it, but they don't move.

```
import turtle as trtl
import random as rand
import leaderboard as lb

#-----game configuration-----
# To view in trinket change the values of font_size, spot_size, and 
# screen_size by half
font_setup = ("Arial", 20, "normal")
timer = 30
counter_interval = 1000 
timer_up = False
score = 0

#-----initialize the turtles-----

score_writer = trtl.Turtle()
score_writer.hideturtle()
score_writer.penup()
score_writer.goto(360, 160) # x,y set to fit on smaller screen
score_writer.pendown()
#score_writer.showturtle()

counter =  trtl.Turtle()
counter.hideturtle()
counter.penup()
counter.goto(-160, 160) # x,y set to fit on smaller screen
counter.pendown()
#counter.showturtle()

#-----game functions-----

# countdown function
def countdown():
  global timer, timer_up
  counter.clear()
  if timer <= 0:
    counter.write("Time's Up", font=font_setup)
    timer_up = True

  else:
    counter.write("Timer: " + str(timer), font=font_setup)
    timer -= 1
    counter.getscreen().ontimer(countdown, counter_interval) 

# update and display the score
def update_score():
  global score
  score = score + 1
  score_writer.clear()
  score_writer.write(score, font=font_setup)

# what happens when the spot is clicked
def patty_tapped(x,y):
  global timer_up
  if (not timer_up):
    update_score()
  

#-----setup-----
patty_image = "patty.gif" # Store the file name of your shape

wn = trtl.Screen()
wn.setup(width=1.0, height=1.0)
wn.addshape(patty_image) # Make the screen aware of the new file
wn.bgpic("underwater.png")

letters = ['A','S','D','F','G','H','J','K','L'] #list of letters

pattyList = []
pattyLetters = []

for i in range(5): # range 5 = the amount of pattys on the grill
  pattyList.append(trtl.Turtle())
  pattyLetters.append(rand.choice(letters)) #TO MAKE RANDOM


#-----functions-----
# given a turtle, set that turtle to be shaped by the image file
def draw_patty(index):
  pattyList[index].pu()
  pattyList[index].shape(patty_image)
  wn.tracer(False)
  pattyList[index].setx(rand.randint(-275,275)) #reset patty pos.
  pattyList[index].sety(rand.randint(-90,0))  #reset patty pos.
  pattyList[index].sety(pattyList[index].ycor()-35)
  pattyList[index].color("white")
  pattyList[index].write(pattyLetters[index], align="center", font=("Arial", 40, "bold"))
  pattyList[index].sety(pattyList[index].ycor()+35)
  pattyList[index].showturtle()
  wn.tracer(True)
  wn.update()

  
def drop_patty(index):
    pattyList[index].pu()
    pattyList[index].clear()
    pattyList[index].sety(-150)
    pattyList[index].hideturtle()
    pattyLetters[index] = rand.choice(letters)
    draw_patty(index)

    

def typedA():
  for i in range (5):
    if pattyLetters[i] == 'A':
      drop_patty(i)
      update_score()

def typedS():
  for i in range (5):
    if pattyLetters[i] == 'S':
      drop_patty(i)
      update_score()

def typedD():
  for i in range (5):
    if pattyLetters[i] == 'D':
      drop_patty(i)
      update_score()

def typedF():
  for i in range (5):
    if pattyLetters[i] == 'F':
      drop_patty(i)
      update_score()


def typedG():
  for i in range (5):
    if pattyLetters[i] == 'G':
      drop_patty(i)
      update_score()

def typedH():
  for i in range (5):
    if pattyLetters[i] == 'H':
      drop_patty(i)
      update_score()

def typedJ():
  for i in range (5):
    if pattyLetters[i] == 'J':
      drop_patty(i)
      update_score()

def typedK():
  for i in range (5):
    if pattyLetters[i] == 'K':
      drop_patty(i)
      update_score()

def typedL():
  for i in range (5):
    if pattyLetters[i] == 'L':
       drop_patty(i)
       update_score()
#-----function calls-----

for i in range(5):
  draw_patty(i)
wn.onkeypress(typedA, 'a')
wn.onkeypress(typedS, 's')
wn.onkeypress(typedD, 'd')
wn.onkeypress(typedF, 'f')
wn.onkeypress(typedG, 'g')
wn.onkeypress(typedH, 'h')
wn.onkeypress(typedJ, 'j')
wn.onkeypress(typedK, 'k')
wn.onkeypress(typedL, 'l')


  
# starting the game
def start_game():
  counter.getscreen().ontimer(countdown, counter_interval)


#----------events----------
start_game()
wn = trtl.Screen()
wn.mainloop()
wn.listen()
```

Comment: You need to add log statements to this or run in an IDE with breakpoints. Try to edit your post to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem:

```
wn.mainloop()
wn.listen()
```

Once you call `mainloop()`, you turn control over to tkinter's event loop and nothing after this call is excuted until turtle shuts down.  Do the `listen()` before `mainloop()`, otherwise your keystrokes will be ignored.

Here's a rework of your code with the above fix and a number of turtle and Python tweaks:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import choice, randint

#-----game configuration-----
# To view in trinket change the values of font_size,
# spot_size, and screen_size by half
FONT_SETUP = ('Arial', 20, 'normal')

COUNTER_INTERVAL = 1000

LETTERS = ['A', 'S', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L']  # list of letters

PATTIES = 5
PATTY_IMAGE = "patty.gif"  # Store the file name of your shape

# global variables
timer = 30
timer_up = False
score = 0

#-----game functions-----

# countdown function
def countdown():
    global timer, timer_up

    counter.clear()

    if timer <= 0:
        counter.write("Time's Up", font=FONT_SETUP)
        timer_up = True
    else:
        counter.write("Timer: " + str(timer), font=FONT_SETUP)
        timer -= 1
        screen.ontimer(countdown, COUNTER_INTERVAL)

# update and display the score
def update_score():
    global score

    score += 1
    score_writer.clear()
    score_writer.write(score, font=FONT_SETUP)

# starting the game
def start_game():
    screen.ontimer(countdown, COUNTER_INTERVAL)

#-----functions-----
# given a turtle, set that turtle to be shaped by the image file
def draw_patty(index):
    screen.tracer(False)

    pattyList[index].setx(randint(-275, 275))  # reset patty position
    y = randint(-90, 0)
    pattyList[index].sety(y - 35)
    pattyList[index].write(pattyLetters[index], align='center', font=('Arial', 40, 'bold'))
    pattyList[index].sety(y)
    pattyList[index].showturtle()

    screen.tracer(True)
    screen.update()

def drop_patty(index):
    pattyList[index].hideturtle()
    pattyList[index].clear()

    pattyLetters[index] = choice(LETTERS)

    draw_patty(index)

def typedLetter(letter):
    while letter in pattyLetters:
        drop_patty(pattyLetters.index(letter))
        update_score()

def typedA():
    typedLetter('A')

def typedS():
    typedLetter('S')

def typedD():
    typedLetter('D')

def typedF():
    typedLetter('F')

def typedG():
    typedLetter('G')

def typedH():
    typedLetter('H')

def typedJ():
    typedLetter('J')

def typedK():
    typedLetter('K')

def typedL():
    typedLetter('L')

screen = Screen()

#-----initialize the turtles-----

score_writer = Turtle()
score_writer.hideturtle()
score_writer.penup()
score_writer.goto(360, 160)  # x,y set to fit on smaller screen

counter = Turtle()
counter.hideturtle()
counter.penup()
counter.goto(-160, 160)  # x,y set to fit on smaller screen

#-----setup-----

screen.setup(width=1.0, height=1.0)
screen.addshape(PATTY_IMAGE)  # Make the screen aware of the new file
screen.bgpic("underwater.png")

pattyList = []
pattyLetters = []

for i in range(PATTIES):
    patty = Turtle()
    patty.penup()
    patty.shape(PATTY_IMAGE)
    patty.color('white')
    pattyList.append(patty)

    pattyLetters.append(choice(LETTERS))

    draw_patty(i)

#-----function calls-----

screen.onkeypress(typedA, 'a')
screen.onkeypress(typedS, 's')
screen.onkeypress(typedD, 'd')
screen.onkeypress(typedF, 'f')
screen.onkeypress(typedG, 'g')
screen.onkeypress(typedH, 'h')
screen.onkeypress(typedJ, 'j')
screen.onkeypress(typedK, 'k')
screen.onkeypress(typedL, 'l')
screen.listen()

#----------events----------

start_game()

screen.mainloop()
```